# Capture Mobile Number of Customer who Reply STOP

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

We want to capture mobile number or contact Key of customer who reply STOP keyword for unsubscribe.
We have tried to do this using InsertDE function in Custom Response Text as follows but it fails.

```
%%[
InsertDE('DEname' , 'fieldname' , MOBILE_NUMBER)
]%%
```

How can we capture Contact Key or mobile number of customer who reply STOP Keyword in another DE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with `InsertDE` function. **It only works in emails**.

> Use this function with email messages at send time only. No value is
>   returned. This function applies to email messages at send time only.

You need to use `InsertData` instead. Use the same code, just change the function's name:

```
%%[
InsertData('DEname' , 'fieldname' , MOBILE_NUMBER)
]%%
```

> Use this function with landing pages, SMS and MMS messages in
>   MobileConnect, push messages in MobilePush, and messages in
>   GroupConnect.

**Reference:**

- [InsertData](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/insertdata.htm)
- [InsertDE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/insertde.htm)